# Charging mobile phones in Mongolia

Tags: cellphones, power, mongolia, remote-locations

I often find mobile phones useful when travelling. On the practical side, they can be helpful when trying to find a place, and also looking up information about a place. On a more non-essential note, I sometimes use them to show people pictures of something I'm talking about.

In Mongolia, is it common for accommodation (tourist gers in particular) to lack electricity and/or only have a very limited number of powerpoints? If so, what options are available to recharge mobile phones during the daytime? Is it possible to recharge them using some sort of hand generator or solar power?

Comment: There are all sorts of solar powered phone charging devices, roll up panels, fold up devices, try googling a bit, you will get pages of options.  You have to shop around to make sure it puts out enough current for your phone model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Tom is right, you'll get more out of Google.

Waka-Waka.com provides an example of such a common use solar panel as you might be a looking for.

Most gers though, I found on our trip through central Mongolia, have electricity through solar panels/car batteries, and the locals are really friendly; I can only imagine them being helpful when asked for some power.

I would recommend turning off your phone when not used and, if you were planning to take pictures with your phone, to bring a separate camera as well as your phone. A separate camera provides you with another battery, and typically uses that charge more efficiently (as there are no background processes running, like connecting to/searching for a mobile network).